# std::find returns vec.end() regardless of whether or not value is in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, find

First, I create two pointers to the vectors (which are themselves accessed via another pointer). This is not a necessary step, but the problem persists regardless of whether or not I use a pointer-to-a-pointer or the pointer itself.

```
std::vector<Int_t> * FV = &DataStorage->fFirstVector;
std::vector<Float_t> * SV = &DataStorage->fSecondVector;
```

Then I invoke the find function. My purpose in doing this is, if the values *firstDatum* and *secondDatum* are **not** in the first or second vectors respectively, push *both* values into their respective vector.

```
if( std::find(FV->begin(), FV->end(), firstDatum) == FV->end()
    or std::find(SV->begin(), SV->end(), secondDatum) == SV->end() )
{
        FV->push_back(firstDatum);
        SV->push_back(secondDatum);
}
```

The problem is that *firstDatum* and *secondDatum* are being pushed into the vector regardless of whether or not they're already there, resulting in two vectors filled with many duplicates. The vectors are exactly the same size, with exactly as many entries as there are data points (so there it's not that the first clause is evaluating true, and pushing a duplicate into the 2nd vector).

Is there any obvious mistake I'm making here? Can anyone give me some advice? I've been screwing around with this for a while now and just can't manage to figure out what's going wrong. I've checked all the data-types, tried abandoning unnecessary pointers, etc., but can't figure it out.

(The only restrictions: I need to be using vectors, and similarly the only way to access these vectors is via the *DataStorage* pointer.)

Comment: Back to basics: build a truth table for your condition and check if it matches your assumptions.

Comment: Another problem is using `==` on floats is often difficult to predict.  Of course, epsilon tests are also difficult to predict.

Comment: @NeilKirk Ah. Why do I need two if statements? If one is true or if the other is true (or if both are true), then I'd like for both values to be put into the vectors.

Comment: == on floats is not difficult to predict. It is as exact as it can be. It would not create duplicates. However... @AmagicalFishy *how* do you determine the vectors have duplicates?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I print out their entries in another script and see that 50% of them are duplicate ones.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy then you get duplicates: it doesn't matter if `secondDatum` will become a duplicate because if `firstDatum` won't then that's enough reason to enter the `if` body. Both vectors will always have the same size, because the code always pushes to both at once.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy *how* do you print them out? The correct way to test for duplicates is with `==`. A simple piece of code that tests for the presence of duplicates using `==` is  `std::set<T>(v.begin(), v.end()).size() != v.size()`. Visual inspection only works if done very carefully, starting from the output.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I understand that one or the other would cause BOTH points of data to be pushed in, but that's what I want, and that isn't what I'm trying to fix (as stated in the post). — The vectors are saved in another file, which I then parse with a python script. I use == to test for duplicates and then I explicitly print out the entries to see if they really are duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean for that to happen.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Your code provided will result in duplicates for some inputs.

Comment: One way to debug would be to separate the if statements, and put the results of each if into a bool variable. Then set a breakpoint when the push_back is done and see which condition caused it to succeed. Something like this:

    bool noFirst = std::find(FV->begin(), FV->end(), firstDatum) == FV->end();
    bool noSecond = std::find(SV->begin(), SV->end(), secondDatum) == SV->end();
    if (noFirst || noSecond)
    { 
        ... //set a breakpoint inside here
    }

Comment: @r.martinhofernandes It is difficult to predict, in that reasonably smart people predict the result wrong without learning how IEEE floats work, and even after they know how IEEE floats work in non-trivial situations they won't be able to work out if two IEEE floats are equal without a lot of effort.  And insofar as you want floats to be a model of reals, `==` on two arbitrary constructed reals is not realizable in our universe.  It isn't random, it is just difficult to predict what it will do in situations beyond toy ones.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Push_if_not_found(
    std::vector<int> * FV,
    std::vector<float> * SV,
    int firstDatum,
    float secondDatum )
{
    if( std::find( FV->begin(), FV->end(), firstDatum ) == FV->end() )
    {
        FV->push_back(firstDatum);
    }

    if( std::find( SV->begin(), SV->end(), secondDatum ) == SV->end() )
    {
        SV->push_back(secondDatum);
    }
}

int main()
{

    struct ds
    {
        std::vector<int> fFirstVector;
        std::vector<float> fSecondVector;
    } ds1;

    ds1.fFirstVector.push_back(1);
    ds1.fSecondVector.push_back(1);

    ds * DataStorage = &ds1;
    std::vector<int> * FV = &DataStorage->fFirstVector;
    std::vector<float> * SV = &DataStorage->fSecondVector;

    Push_if_not_found( FV, SV, 1, 1 );

    if( FV->size() != 1 || SV->size() != 1)
    {
        cout << "FAILED" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Push_if_not_found( FV, SV, 2, 1 );

    if( FV->size() != 2 || SV->size() != 1)
    {
        cout << "FAILED" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   Push_if_not_found( FV, SV, 2, 2 );

    if( FV->size() != 2 || SV->size() != 2)
    {
        cout << "FAILED" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
   Push_if_not_found( FV, SV, 3, 3 );

    if( FV->size() != 3 || SV->size() != 3)
    {
        cout << "FAILED" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for( auto v : ds1.fFirstVector )
    {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for( auto v : ds1.fSecondVector )
    {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```